# D3 Transition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I am new to D3 and trying to complete a transition of circle elements and a line for 2 datasets. The line is transitioning fine, but the circles are acting "crazy" and I can't figure out why, when it seems like such a simple transition.

Here is the code + the two simple datasets used. Thank you!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style> 

  body { font: 12px Arial;}

  path { 
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 2;
fill: none;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

 .dot {
fill: red;
stroke: black;
  }

  </style>
  <body>

<div id="option">
<input name="updateButton" 
       type="button" 
       value="Update" 
       onclick="updateData()" />
</div>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>
 // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the initial data
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

//Add the circles
svg.append("g").attr("class","dot")
   .selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
   .attr("r",5);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

});

// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {

// Get the data again
d3.tsv("data-alt.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Make the changes
    svg.select(".line").transition()   // change the line
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

svg.selectAll("circle").transition()  //change the circles
    .duration(750)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    svg.select(".x.axis").transition() // change the x axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.select(".y.axis").transition() // change the y axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxis);
 });
}

</script>
</body>


data.tsv

date    close
1-May-12    58.13
30-Apr-12   53.98
27-Apr-12   67.00
26-Apr-12   89.70
25-Apr-12   99.00
24-Apr-12   130.28
23-Apr-12   166.70
20-Apr-12   234.98
19-Apr-12   345.44
18-Apr-12   443.34
17-Apr-12   543.70
16-Apr-12   580.13
13-Apr-12   605.23
12-Apr-12   622.77
11-Apr-12   626.20
10-Apr-12   628.44
9-Apr-12    636.23
5-Apr-12    633.68
4-Apr-12    624.31
3-Apr-12    629.32
2-Apr-12    618.63
30-Mar-12   599.55
29-Mar-12   609.86
28-Mar-12   617.62
27-Mar-12   614.48
26-Mar-12   606.98

data-alt.tsv

date    close
10-May-12   99.55
8-May-12    76.86
6-May-12    67.62
4-May-12    64.48
2-May-12    60.98
1-May-12    58.13
30-Apr-12   53.98 
27-Apr-12   67.00
26-Apr-12   89.70
25-Apr-12   99.00
24-Apr-12   90.28
23-Apr-12   106.70
20-Apr-12   94.98
19-Apr-12   85.44
18-Apr-12   73.34
17-Apr-12   53.70
16-Apr-12   50.13
13-Apr-12   65.23
12-Apr-12   62.77
11-Apr-12   66.20
10-Apr-12   68.44
9-Apr-12    66.23
5-Apr-12    63.68
4-Apr-12    64.31
3-Apr-12    69.32
2-Apr-12    61.63
```

Comment: What do you mean by crazy? Can you post a running example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circles never have their data updated. The transition currently shows them moving from the first values scaled by the first scale to the first values scaled by the second scale.

If you update the data attached the circles, it should look like what you're expecting:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).transition()  //change the circles
    .duration(750)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });
```

This assumes that each data set has the same number of months in it and that they have the same order in each. If first assumption isn't true, you'll need to handle [entrances and exits](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218); if the second isn't true you'll need a [key function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221).

Comment: Thank you Adam! That absolutely solved it. I could have sworn that I had tried that already but I guess not. Thanks again.